# Doesn't get searchinput via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a searchfield which refers to a function to look into my database and get the people I need. That works fine with php, but when I try to do the same with ajax, it fails.

The searchinput never get posted.

Here's the code. I hope someone has a clue why. Thanks.

**Doctor.class.php**

```
public function searchPatients($p_sSearch, $p_iUserid) {
    include("Connection.php"); //open db

    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers 
                WHERE UserLastname = '".$p_sSearch."'
                and fk_DoctorId = ".$p_iUserid.";";
        $rResult = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        return $rResult;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

**ajax/save.php**

```
include("../classes/Doctor.class.php");

$oDoctor = new Doctor();
    try
    {
    $oDoctor->Search = $_POST['searchinput'];

        $oDoctor->searchPatients($_POST['searchinput'], $_POST['userid']);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**doctorindex.php**

```
$("#search_overview").hide();
var searchinput = $("#searchinput").val();
$("#searchbutton").live("click", function() {       
    $.post("ajax/save.php", {searchinput: searchinput, 
                            userid: <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>},
            function(data) 
            { 
                $("#patients_overview").hide();
                $("#search_overview").fadeIn();
            });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What fails exactly - does the request get made? What comes back? (Use e.g. Firebug's "Net" tab to find out.)

Comment: Why are you passing that session variable via the POST data? It is already going to be available in `$_SESSION` (where the user can't tamper with it).

Comment: Yeah, when I use firebug I get this: http://d.pr/NYKX. So the searchinput doesn't get posted. And I really don't have a clue why..

Comment: You are calling `ajax/save.php` not `ajax.php` and running function `searchPatients` and here you posts `findPatients`. Also we don't know normal flow of application, if there are others conditions that could terminate the script. [edit] After looking at firebug screen I think it's problem with html, maybe missing id in searchinput?

Comment: You should narrow down your problem to either "Why does this PHP not output the JavaScript/HTML I expect?" or "Why does this JavaScript error / provide unexpected results?" There is a lot we don't know about your problem (such as what sort of values the id could hold. If, for example, that wasn't a number, then it would break because strings have to be quoted in JS. It would be much easier to identify these problems if we weren't trying to run the PHP in our heads to try to figure out what it is going to be generating.

Comment: @KimWouters - You'll need to open up more of your HTML.  Everything looks fine, I expect you're not getting the value of 'searchinput' properly based on your firebug.

Comment: Ok, here's my html for the searchbutton and the searchinput: `<form action="" method="POST">
  <input id="searchinput" name="searchinput"/>
  <input type="submit" value="search" id="searchbutton" name="searchbutton"/>
 </form>`

On the top of the page from doctorindex.php I use this to call on the function: ` $searchPatients = $oDoctor->searchPatients($_POST['searchinput'], $_SESSION['id']);
`

And the id can only be a number, the searchinput can only be a string. Hope that does give you guys some extra info. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are getting search input value on page load (when it's empty), not after clicking search button (when you have typed something into it).

You may try:

- getting search input value directly in `.post`: `{searchinput:$("#searchinput").val()}`
- moving `var searchinput` into callback function for click event

Comment: This works perfectly to get the searchinput posted. Thanks. However it doesn't work yet, at least I get the value in. :) Now when I echo the $sql to see if it works, the sql doesn't update zo I get this: `SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE UserLastname = '' and fk_DoctorId = 9;`

Is that something that stands on the wrong place as well?